# Console tells me object exists; rake test does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

I am new to ruby on rails and have worked through some tutorials. Now I'm trying to build an app of my own and encountering issues. Many I have been able to work work around, which is a great learning experience, but this one I'm stumped by.

I have created a model, migrated it, there's one model called CardSymbol, it consists of an id field and a name. I have this in my seeds.rb file which I have run.

```
CardSymbol.create!(name: "hat")
```

I can open up the rails console, type this in...

```
CardSymbol.find_by(name: "hat").id
```

...and I get 1, the primary key, this is what I expect. So I know the record is in the database.

And yet in one of my test.rb files, I have the exact same code, but when I run bundle exec rake test and I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

So... this appears to be telling me it has failed to find the record that I know exists. I tried setting Rails.env in my test file to development or test, as "different environment" was all I could think of as a solution that fits the symptoms, but it didn't help. What am I missing here?

PS I'm pretty convinced the test code is not the issue but as multiple people have asked for it, I stripped it all back to the following & still got the error (note it's an error, not a test failure).

```
require 'test_helper'

class CardTypeTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @example_card_symbol = CardSymbol.find_by(name: "hat").id
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert 1==1
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the test file in the setup method, add this line as the first line.

```
Rails.application.load_seed
```

This will then load the data from seeds.rb into the test database, and it all works.

With thanks to Frederick Cheung whose answer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: ...and I will make this the accepted answer in 2 days (wow, I really, really, hate all these limitations for having low rep)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things that could be going on. First try running `rake db:test:prepare`. This will make sure your test database is migrated and setup. One thing to note is that when you're running things in your local console you're connected to a development database. However when you're running tests they will be connecting a separate test database.

The next issue to consider is that you should never try and access and object in the database if you didn't create it in the test. All tests should be able to run solo, meaning they create the data they need, test for it and clean up when they are done.

EDIT: Updates after test was posted.

So in your test you're searching for something that doesn't yet exist. I'm more familiar with Rspec but the following test should pass.

```
require 'test_helper'

class CardTypeTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @example_card_symbol = CardSymbol.create(name: "hat")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @example_card_symbol.valid?
    # or maybe: assert @example_card_symbol.persisted?
  end
end
```

This test will assert that the card symbol create statement returned an object. It's not a great test but will get you moving in the right direction.

Things to follow up on that would be helpful for you: Rspec (a different test sweet debatably more favored in the Rails community), FactoryGirl, DatabaseCleaner

Comment: I agree with Tyler. Your tests should be as self-contained as possible. Have your test create the record. For the most part expect your test DB to be mostly empty. Tools like FactoryGirl can be helpful for generating your test case data during each test.

Comment: I want this record in the database at the end of the day anyway... trying to kill two birds with one stone. I see the wisdom in keeping things separate though... just not how I'm used to doing things! PS Why does the seeds file even exist then?

Comment: Tried rake db:test:prepare, didn't help, have posted test code above

Comment: The seeds file is for creating data for the development environment so you can play with an application, see how it would look with data in it, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The seeds file is not loaded into your test database, furthermore running the tests wipes the test database.

Use fixtures or factories for data that should exists in tests.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted your test with your question but I have a theory as to what is wrong so I am going to take a stab at it.  In your test try this:

```
card_symbol = CardSymbol.create!(name: "hat")
card_symbol.reload
```

Honestly I am not sure why but sometimes Active Record uses a caching mechanism and you get a stale copy.  I would love to hear someone weigh in on why this happens.